# When using float having error?

Tags: html, css

When I am using the CSS float Property its working partly perfect 
as we can see in the HTML that ID #contact float perfect in the right side but the ID #workExperiance should be below the full name in normal order how to do that its also floating. 
Require detailed explanation

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  color: #4EC5C1;
}

#name {
  float: left;
}

#contact {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Full Name Resume</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <section>
      <h1 id="name"><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="contact">
        <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
        <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
        <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
  <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `div{float:left; width:100%;}` it'll work

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em; 
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div{float:left; width:100%;}
.main{color: #4EC5C1;}
#name{float:left;}
#contact{float:right;list-style-type:none;}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Full Name  Resume</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
   </head> 
  <body>
    <div>
    <section><h1 id = "name"><span class = "main">full </span> Name</h1></section><section>
    <ul id="contact"><li><span class = "main">Cell:</span>  +1-000000000</li>
      <li><span class = "main">Email: </span>  aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
      <li><span class = "main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li></ul></section>
      </div>
      <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
    </body>
    
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear: both` Read more about **[Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)**

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them. The clear property applies to both floating and
>   non-floating elements.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section#workExperiance {
  clear: both;
}

.main {
  color: #4EC5C1;
}

#name {
  float: left;
}

#contact {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <section>
    <h1 id="name"><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <ul id="contact">
      <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
      <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
      <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
<section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
```

*P.S: And better use `div` in this case and no need to use `section`. Normally `section` use for parent `wrapper`.*

Comment: here they have not used anything why ?https://codepen.io/techie4good/pen/RGNBPQ?q=resume&limit=techie4good

Comment: they have not used table sir anywhere

Comment: @RishitShah Which part of this demo? i saw below table. you mean header? there is no text under `Kasey Champion`. Now why you compare your code with that? `clear: both` solved your problem? so it's solved.

Comment: sorry sir i am not comparing sir i am learning from it so just ask you why to add new code

Comment: As i said your code structure is different, and over there no text used under. for each structure you may need do something different. @RishitShah

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em; 
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.main{color: #4EC5C1;}
#name{float:left; display:block;}
#contact{float:right;list-style-type:none; width:50%; padding:0; display:block}
#workExperiance{
float:left;
display:block;
}
#left{
width:40%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Full Name  Resume</title>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
   </head> 
  <body>
    <div>
    <div id="left">
    <section><h1 id = "name"><span class = "main">full </span> Name</h1></section> <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section></div><section>
    <ul id="contact"><li><span class = "main">Cell:</span>  +1-000000000</li>
      <li><span class = "main">Email: </span>  aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
      <li><span class = "main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li></ul></section>
      </div>
      
    </body>
    
  </html>
```

Always use `display:block` and special width when floating